# PHP code dynamic evaluation

Tags: php

Imagine we have 2 files, one called `1.php` with the following code:

```
<?php
    $hello = "Hello from 1";
?>
```

and `2.php` with the following code:

```
<?php
    function LoadPage( $page )
    {
        $f = fopen( $page, 'r+' );  
        $content = fread( $f, filesize($page) );
        fclose( $f );
        return $content;
    }

    function GetEvalContent( $content )
    {
        $var = "";
        ob_start();
        eval( "?>" . $content . "<?" );
        $var = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $var;
    }

    $hello = "hello from 2";

    echo $hello . '<br/>';

    $content = LoadPage( '1.php' );
    GetEvalContent( $content );

    echo $hello;
?>
```

So what the `2.php` does is load the content of `1.php` and evaluate the php code inside it. Now what I want to do is during the evaluation of `1.php`, variable $hello changes to "hello from 1". However if you execute `2.php` you always get:

```
"hello from 2"
"hello from 2"
```

instead of getting

```
"hello from 2"
"hello from 1"
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before and if so, how would you fix it?

Comment: Just fyi `eval( "?>" . $content . "<?" );` is not valid syntax.

Comment: It is a valid syntax. The whole point is to evaluate $content which has mixture of php code and non-php code. Please google it first!

Comment: Hmm, seems you're right. I didn't realize that, because I've been trained to avoid `eval`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a much easier way to do this.  Use PHP's [`include`](http://php.net/include).

1.php

```
<?php
   $hello = "Hello from 1";
?>
```

2.php

```
<?php
   $hello = "hello from 2";
   echo $hello;
   include '1.php';
   echo $hello;
?>
```

UPDATE (not tested):

```
function includeFile($file){
  global $hello;  // Use the global variable $hello
                  // this will make the include sets $hello correctly
  ob_start();
  include $file;  // Remember any variables set here will be in this scope,
                  // not the global scope (unless you add them to the global line above)
  $var = ob_get_contents();  // This will contain anything echoed to the screen
                             // from the included file
  ob_end_clean();
  return $var;
}

$hello = "hello from 2";
echo $hello;
$file = '1.php';
$output = includeFile($file);
echo $hello;
echo $output;
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if you want to dynamically change the name of the file. Imagine, based on user's action, you want to evaluate/load 4.php instead of 1.php.

Comment: @Ali: Yes it would.  `$file = '4.php';  include($file);`

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't clear it enough. The whole point of that was to  evaluate the file and store the result into a variable. if you use include or require, you will flush it to the browser.

Comment: @Ali: No, you did not explain that.  In your example, you just showed setting a variable, not echoing anything to the screen.  Try adding `ob_start` before the `include` then `ob_get_contents` and `ob_end_clean` after it.

Comment: Thanks, however, The problem is that I want to put all those into a single function which can be called in my code multiple times. Would it be possible to wrap all those into a function somehow?

Comment: @Ali: Yes, just wrap it in a function, just remember the scope your variables are in.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your eval() within a function, so the `$hello` in the included file will be part of only the function's scope. It will not affect the `$hello` that's defined outside the function (which is global scope).

You'd need to put the `global` keyword into your included file, unless you want to write your own PHP parser to figure out what variables are being defined in the included file and auto-globalize them.

However, in the bigger picture... WHY? eval is a horribly evil ugly construct, and you're opening yourself up to a world of debugging pain, let alone the security issues.

Comment: Did not work! I have added global keyword before $hello in 1.php and it didn't work.

Comment: There's also the fact that `eval( "?>" . $content . "<?" );` is not valid syntax.

Comment: if you have html and php code mixed, you have to use eval( "?>" . $content . "<?" );

Comment: @Ali: no. the eval'd text has to be valid PHP code, WITHOUT the `?>/<?` delimiters. `eval('Hello')` would fail, but `eval('$txt = 'Hello';)` will work.

Comment: I disagree with you. The whole point of adding those delimiters is to evaluate an staring that has mixture of php code and non-php code.

Comment: @Marc: Apparently `eval('?><?php $hello = "test";?><?')` _is_ valid.  WTF?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `require` or `include`? [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Example:

```
$hello = "Hello from 2";
echo $hello;
include("1.php");
echo $hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$GLOBALS['hello']` instead of `$hello`

PS: Don't forget `eval` is evil ;)

Comment: Also, `eval( "?>" . $content . "<?" );` is not valid syntax.

Comment: How about if I have mixture of HTML and PHP code? how would you run the code then?

Comment: @Ali: Turns out, that is valid.  Weird.